# formatting mail in PHP

Tags: php, email

I am sending a link in a mail using which user will be redirected to a different page.

I want to send the link on the **click here** but the formatting has some mistake..

```
if ($email = $_REQUEST['email'])
{

    $to   = $email;
    $from = "admin@abc.com";

    $subject = "Password reset link";
    $headers = $from;

    $link = "To reset your password click below link";
    $link = "
    <a href="'http://www.abc.com/changepassword.php'">Click Here</a>";

    $message = $link;
    mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Comment: You should remove the inner double quotes

Comment: $link="
<a href='http://www.abc.com/changepassword.php'>Click Here</a>"; ?

Comment: You have to send the Mail with `Content-Type: text/html` in the header. Else it gets not parsed by the displaying e-mail client.

Comment: You are over-writing the `$link` variable.  use `$link.="<a>...whatever...</a>"` to append the link

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
$link="
<a href="'http://www.abc.com/changepassword.php'">Click Here</a>";
```

to

```
$link .= "
<a href='http://www.abc.com/changepassword.php'>Click Here</a>";
```

Comment: He's over-writing his `$link` value.. should use `.=` to avoid that

Comment: @msturdy Did not notice that at all.

Comment: +1 now, well, until the guy defines the vague "mistakes" in his formatting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Better :

```
$link .= '<a href="http://www.abc.com/changepassword.php">Click Here</a>';
```

PHP parse the double quotes strings, it's a quite faster like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get all the information in the $link variable when you send, and the link is not correct formatted.

```
$link = 'To reset your password click below link';
$link .= '<a href="http://www.abc.com/changepassword.php">Click Here</a>';
```